# Various mails in chain

Tags: american-english, british-english, compounds

Which is more correct to say

> 1. See mail trail
> 2. See trail mail

I want to know the right sentence to use when writing mail. Some people use *mail trail* while some use *trail mail*. It puts me in a confusion that I really want to understand the right grammar to use.

Can someone explain the difference between the two forms? Which form is more acceptable and/or common?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by either *mail trail* or *trail mail*. What is it that you're trying to express that you think one or both of those phrases represents? Are you perhaps talking about a *chain letter*?

Comment: Well, my first thought is "chain mail", but many people find that concept impenetrable.  Perhaps you should specify whether you're referring to postal mail or email.

Comment: @HotLicks Chainmail is hardly  impenetrable to a good English longbow.

Comment: @tchrist - Should I say "touché" or "touchy"?

Answer (score 1):

I have not encountered "trail mail", and [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mail+trail%2Ctrail+mail&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmail%20trail%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmail%20trail%3B%2Cc1) concurs. It is likely you mean "mail trail", however the exact phrase depends on what you mean.

A "mail trail" is a single trail made up of many items of mail. Many letter (or emails or messages) which, when put together, tell a single story. Individual  messages could be referred to as "trail mail".